# CAS number of currently logged users

Tags: cas, zabbix

I'm trying to monitor the number of logged in users into CAS. Ideally I would like to read that number from a log file or web service and send it to our service monitoring system (zabbix).

How can I get the number of current valid sessions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this link for more info please: http://jasig.github.io/cas/4.2.x/installation/Monitoring-Statistics.html